# Can't find tables and data of my H2 database

Tags: h2

A webapp is using following configuration to store some data in DB:

```
spring.datasource.continueOnError=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
```

I was trying to reach this DB using H2 Console, but something is wrong. There are no tables even though I know they were created. I can also access any made up JDBC:URL like jdbc:h2:mem:fakeXYZ just as well with same result. What is goning on here? How can I see this DB tables and data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC URL specifies a [named in-memory](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) database which by default only will be available for connections from within the same virtual machine.

You can either change the URL to use a file-based database, or you will have to [start a TCP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318116/how-to-run-h2-database-in-server-mode) to allow for connections from other processes.